# Sort two list string with the value of the first list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have one list string in kotlin
I want to put them in order from Mon to Sun
as the order of the days of the week

Please help me !

`Sun 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Mon 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Tue 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Web 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Thu 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Fri 11:30 am - 9:30 pm Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm`

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to convert a timeframe that starts a week with **Sunday** into a week with **Monday**.

Here are my assumptions:

1. Sunday is **always** at the front of the given string
2. Time & Date format is **consistent**.
3. There are no **equal** days in the given string (ex. SUN & SUN)

Here is my algo based on your given constraints:

```
    var str = "Sun 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Mon 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Tue 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Web 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Thu 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Fri 11:30 am - 9:30 pm Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"

    var counter = 0
    
    //Just looks for the index when Sunday is done. It is given that a single Date and Time is done when it reaches AM or PM twice.
    for (i in 1 until str.length) {
        val time = String(charArrayOf(str[i - 1], str[i]))
        if (time == "pm" || time == "am") {
            counter++
        }
        if (counter == 2) {
            str = str.substring(i + 2, str.length) + " " + str.substring(0, i + 1)
            break
        }
    }

    println(str)
```

**However**, if my assumption is wrong, and you want to parse the given string entirely by chronological order, I can achieve it easily using `HashSets` and `Lists`. If not, you could expound upon your problem a bit more.

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: ex Sun 11:30 am - 9:00 is one item in List<String> , the days of the week are each item in list<String> , and I want to sort them monday to sunday

Comment: can you clarify a bit more? I am still confused. what exactly do you want to achieve? give me some testcases?

Comment: I have one List<String>  as above
Sun 11:30 am - 9:00 pm 
Mon 11:30 am - 9:00 pm
Tue 11:30 am - 9:00 pm
Web 11:30 am - 9:00 pm 
Thu 11:30 am - 9:00 pm
Fri 11:30 am - 9:30 pm
Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm
it will be random and out of order from monday to sunday , and i want it to be rearranged from monday to sunday in any case

Comment: @Jack Can there is equal days in the list? (ex. two Sundays)

Answer (score 0):

To sort elements you need to parse them in the first place. That's tricky in this case because there is no unique separator between them. I'd suggest using regex to determine indices of elements bounds.

Also, you need to define a sorting order for days of the week. The simplest way to do it is to map them with some numbers (Kotlin knows how to sort numbers).

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val input = "Sun 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Mon 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Tue 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Web 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Thu 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Fri 11:30 am - 9:30 pm Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm"
    val daysOfWeekSortingOrder = listOf("Mon", "Tue", "Web", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun").withIndex().associate { it.value to it.index }
    val result = Regex("Mon|Tue|Web|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|$")
        .findAll(input)
        .map { it.groups[0]!!.range.first } //get elements starting indices
        .windowed(size = 2) //get indices of elements bounds
        .map { (from, to) -> input.slice(from until to).trim() } //get elements by their indices
        .sortedBy { daysOfWeekSortingOrder[it.substring(0, 3)] } //get day of the week from element and its sorting order
        .joinToString(separator = " ") //glue elements back

    println(result) //Mon 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Tue 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Web 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Thu 11:30 am - 9:00 pm Fri 11:30 am - 9:30 pm Sat 11:30 am - 9:30 pm Sun 11:30 am - 9:00 pm
}
```